# How to add custom language layout inside Gboard (Google Keyboard), created by me

Tags: keyboard, gboard

The problem is that I want to use modified layout for Google Keyboard and use it inside Gboard app (because of its features).

I don't want to:

- create [separate own InputMethod](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615)
- use another app (Hacker's Keyboard or SwiftKey)

Does anyone know how to edit Gboard `.xml` files maybe? Or do it officially through plugin or some code? PS. I can code.

Comment: Do you want to use the the custom layout within Gboard in another application?  Is the other app a keyboard app that would allow you to use the GBoard within it?

Comment: Gboard does take several system propertie to allow customization of its look and feel such as visible key border and default keyboard height ratio. To my knowledge it seems there's no interface for a full layout customization.

Answer (score -1):

It's very easy - just follow the instructions below:

Open Settings/Language and Input/Gboard/Languages/(Your Language);

Then scroll the keyboard to the right and select whichever input layout suits you best.

Comment: I needed the custom layout, e.g. where I can specify what letters and where would be. You suggest choosing from Google predefined list of languages & layouts. This is not a solution to my question.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry. I guess I didn't know how to read back then :/